# How can I sequentially rename files in a folder using Python, without renaming files in a messy way?

Tags: python, rename, sequential

Hi I hope someone can help me,
i'm trying to rename some .png inside a folder,
0.png
1.png
2.png
...
3000.png

the problem is that it processes files in a messy way, for example 10.png renames it to 3.png
Instead it should be 11.png etc.

I would like it to rename like this instead:
0.png rename to -> 1.png
1.png rename to -> 2.png
...
10.png rename to -> 11.png

Some advice?
Thank you

I tried with this:

```
import os

path = r'/Desktop//Name'
newpath = r'/Desktop/Name2'

count = 1
for f in os.scandir(path):
    if str(f.name).endswith('.png'):
        new_file = '' + str(count)+'.png'
        src = os.path.join(path, f.name)
        dst = os.path.join(newpath, new_file)
        os.rename(src, dst)
        count += 1
 
os.scandir(path).close()
```

Comment: `os.scandir()` returns files in an arbitrary order. If you want to process them in a specific order, you need to sort them.

Comment: Sorting is one way to do that; checking each source file if it exists is perhaps better/easier, IF there are no trailing zeroes (e.g., ```0001.png```).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this without testing, but how about this? It should do what you need.  It appears that maybe there are files other than *.png files in the directory.  If not, then you can simplify this a bit more...

```
import os
import shutil
    
    path = r'/Desktop//Name'
    newpath = r'/Desktop/Name2'
    
    for f in os.scandir(path):
        if str(f.name).endswith('.png'):
            file_number = int(str(f.name).split('.')[0])
            new_file_number = file_number + 1
            new_file = '%s.png' % new_file_number
            src = os.path.join(path, f.name)
            dst = os.path.join(newpath, new_file)
            shutil.move(src, dst)
     
    os.scandir(path).close()
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies, this worked out great for me! The code did what I wanted. Thanks again pedwards